# Best way to lookup elements in GemFire Region

Tags: gemfire, spring-data-gemfire

I have Regions in GemFire with a large number of records.

I need to lookup elements in those Regions for validation purposes.  The lookup is happening for every item we scan; There can be more than 10000 items.

What will be an efficient way to look up element in Regions?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Vikas-

There are several ways in which you can look up, or fetch multiple elements from a GemFire [Region](http://gemfire-90-javadocs.docs.pivotal.io/org/apache/geode/cache/Region.html).

1. As you can see, a GemFire `Region` indirectly implements `java.util.Map`, and so provides all the basic `Map` operations, such as [get(key):value](http://gemfire-90-javadocs.docs.pivotal.io/org/apache/geode/cache/Region.html#get-java.lang.Object-), in addition to several other operations that are **not** available in `Map` like [getAll(Collection keys):Map](http://gemfire-90-javadocs.docs.pivotal.io/org/apache/geode/cache/Region.html#getAll-java.util.Collection-).

> Though, `get(key):value` is not going to be the most "efficient" method for looking up multiple items at once, but `getAll(..)` allows you to pass in a `Collection` of keys for all the values you want returned.  Of course, you have to know the keys of all the values you want in advance, so...

2. You can obtain GemFire's `QueryService` from the `Region` by calling `region`.[`getRegionService()`](http://gemfire-90-javadocs.docs.pivotal.io/org/apache/geode/cache/Region.html#getRegionService--).[`getQueryService()`](http://gemfire-90-javadocs.docs.pivotal.io/org/apache/geode/cache/RegionService.html#getQueryService--).  The [`QueryService`](http://gemfire-90-javadocs.docs.pivotal.io/org/apache/geode/cache/query/QueryService.html) allows you to write GemFire Queries with OQL (or *Object Query Language*).  See *GemFire's User Guide* on [Querying](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/geode/developing/querying_basics/chapter_overview.html) for more details.

> The advantage of using OQL over `getAll(keys)` is, of course, you do not need to know the keys of all the values you might need to validate up front.  If the validation logic is based on some criteria that matches the values that need to be evaluated, you can express this criteria in the OQL Query Predicate.

For example...

`SELECT * FROM /People p WHERE p.age >= 21;`

To call upon the GemFire `QueryService` to write the query above, you would...

```
Region people = cache.getRegion("/People");

...

QueryService queryService = people.getRegionSevice().getQueryService();

Query query = queryService.newQuery("SELECT * FROM /People p WHERE p.age >= $1");

SelectResults<Person> results = (SelectResults<Person>) query.execute(asArray(21));

// process (e.g. validate) the results
```

> OQL Queries can be parameterized and arguments passed to the [Query.execute(args:Object[])](http://gemfire-90-javadocs.docs.pivotal.io/org/apache/geode/cache/query/Query.html#execute-java.lang.Object:A-) method as shown above.  When the appropriate Indexes are added to your GemFire `Regions`, then the performance of your Queries can improve dramatically.  See the *GemFire User Guide* on [creating Indexes](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/geode/developing/query_index/query_index.html).

3. Finally, with GemFire `PARTITION Regions` especially, where your `Region` data is partitioned, or "sharded" and distributed across the nodes (GemFire Servers) in the cluster that host the `Region` of interests (e.g. `/People`), then you can combine querying with GemFire's [Function Execution](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/geode/developing/function_exec/chapter_overview.html) service to query the data locally (to that node), where the data actually exists (e.g. that shard/bucket of the `PARTITION` `Region`containing a subset of the data), rather than bringing the data to you.  You can even encapsulate the "validation" logic in the GemFire `Function` you write.

You will need to use the `RegionFunctionContext` along with the [`PartitionRegionHelper`](http://gemfire-90-javadocs.docs.pivotal.io/org/apache/geode/cache/partition/PartitionRegionHelper.html) to get the local data set of the `Region` to query.  Read the Javadoc of `PartitionRegionHelper` as it shows the particular example you are looking for in this case.

*Spring Data GemFire* can help with many of these concerns...

1. For *Querying*, you can use the SD *Repository abstraction* and [extension](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/gemfire/docs/2.0.0.M4/reference/html/#gemfire-repositories) provided in SDG.
2. For *Function Execution*, you can use SD GemFire's [Function ExeAnnotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/gemfire/docs/2.0.0.M4/reference/html/#function-annotations) support.

Be careful though, using the SD *Repository* abstraction inside a Function context is not just going to limit the query to the "local" data set of the `PARTITION` `Region`.  SD Repos always work on the entire data set of the "logical" `Region`, where the data is necessarily distributed across the nodes in a cluster in a partitioned (sharded) setup.

You should definitely familiarize yourself with GemFire [Partitioned Regions](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/geode/developing/partitioned_regions/chapter_overview.html).

In **summary**...

The approach you choose above really depends on several factors, such as, but not limited to:

1. How you organized the data in the first place (e.g. `PARTITION` vs. `REPLICATE`, which refers to the `Region's` [DataPolicy](http://gemfire-90-javadocs.docs.pivotal.io/org/apache/geode/cache/DataPolicy.html)).
2. How amenable your validation logic is to supplying "criteria" to, say, an OQL Query Predicate to "`SELECT`" **only** the `Region` data you want to validate.  Additionally, efficiency might be further improved by applying appropriate Indexing.
3. How many nodes are in the cluster and how distributed your data is, in which case a `Function` might be the most advantageous approach... i.e. bring the logic to your data rather than the data to your logic.  The later involves selecting the matching data on the nodes where the data resides that could involve several network hops to the nodes containing the data depending on your topology and configuration (i.e. "*single-hop access*", etc), serializing the data to send over the wire thereby increasing the saturation on your network, and so on and so forth).
4. Depending on your UC, other factors to consider are your expiration/eviction policies (e.g. whether data has been overflowed to disk), the frequency of the needed validations based on how often the data changes, etc.

Most of the time, it is better to validate the data on the way in and catch errors early.  Naturally, as data is updated, you may also need to perform subsequent validations, but that is no substitute for early (as possible) verifications where possible.

There are many factors to consider and the optimal approach is not always apparent, so test and make sure your optimizations and overall approach has the desired effect.

Hope this helps!

Regards,
-John

Answer (score 0):

Set up the PDX serializer and use the query service to get your element. "Select element from /region where id=xxx". This will return your element field without deserializing the record. Make sure that id is indexed.

There are other ways to validate quickly if your inbound data is streaming rather than a client lookup, such as the Function Service.